# Accessing the information of the other line from one line in the datatable

Tags: pdf, datatable, datatables, linker, render

I need to access the computer path and open pdf from the link I gave in documentcode. How can I access the techDocPath field in the datatable when I press the (techDocPath) documentCode field? When I click on documentCode, I have to open the pdf in the new tab.

```
 columns: [
    { "data": "typeName" },
    { "data": "subTypeName" },
    { "data": "stokGrup" },
    { "data": "statusName" },
    {
      "data": "documentCode",
       "render": function (data, type, row, full) {
        return "<td><a target='_blank' href=' ' + full.techDocPath +''  style='color:#000; text-decoration: underline;'> " + data + "</a></td>";
}},
  { "data": "documentName" },
  { "data": "materialName" },
  { "data": "gizliMi" },
  { "data": "revisionNo" },
  { "data": "designerAd" },
  { "data": "teknikResimGrubu" },
  { "data":" techDocPath"}
```

Comment: In your column`render` function for `documentCode`, one of the parameters is `row`. That gives you access to all the values in that row of data - so you can access a field such as `row.techDocPath` when you are building your link.

Comment: Also, in your `return` statement, don't include `<td>` or `</td>`. DataTables already knows this is a table cell that you are populating.